# Windows schedulded task execution

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I created a schedulded task in windows in order to launch a .bat file at start or on remote sollicitation. I created it through command lines from my remote computer (I couldn't do it from the target computer itself, it raised an error ... ). 
I used the following command :

```
schtasks /create /S \\<remote_pc> /U <my_login> /P <my_pwd> /tn Launch_simulators_on_start /sc ONSTART /tr C:\Users\SIMULATEUR\Desktop\StartAll.bat
```

I can launch this task from the computer itself or remotely, it works as expected.
However, I would like it to launch on computer restart and when I restart the computer, nothing happens.

Is there a particular option that should be set at creation ? if so, online help is not explicit

has anyone been through this kind of issue ?

thank you

Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

Create a New trigger with a condition of 'At StartUp'. This will run the task on every start\restart of the machine.

[image]

Comment: actually I did it but it does not work either. A collegue of mine showed me a workaround : force auto login and create task with trigger 'at log on' ... this works. But I have another problem, it is launched while the computer is not settled and it does not execute correctly. I tried to set a delay before execution but it does not work. Finally I chose to do full remote process : create the task, launch the task then remove the task ...